Can't get ESLint rule to warn for no-floating-promises
Wheny my ESLint config has
"@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "error"

I get errors for not awaiting promises. When I switch to "off", I get no output. When I set it to "warn", I also get no output.
Is there a way to make it warn?

How are you running eslint?

@Bergi I have a "lint" script in my package.json that just runs "eslint .". Running ESLint v8.43.0
